# x-axis shows 1970 as the starting year of time series dates

Tags: python, matplotlib, datetime, xticks, mplfinance

The dataframe `df` has a datetime index ranging from 2019-12-02 to 2020-01-30 and I can plot it fine using mplfinance's plot function:

[image]

But as soon as I set the tick locators, the tick values get messed up and the years only show "1970."

[image]

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69083927/matplot-lib-generates-date-in-x-axis-from-jan-1970), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64919511/dateformatter-is-bringing-1970-as-year-not-the-original-year-in-the-dataset), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69101233/using-dateformatter-resets-starting-date-to-1970) but still can't figure it out because I'm actually using matplotlib's pyplot to make the plot (instead of pandas), my dates are actually DateTimeIndex, and I already added Year as a separate x-axis.

**Goal**: The format of the second plot above is exactly what I want but the days, months, and years are obviously incorrect. What am I doing wrong?
Here's a reproducible code:

```
import yfinance as yf
import mplfinance as mpf
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

# downloading some sample stock price data from Yahoo Finance
start_date = datetime(2019, 12, 1)
end_date = datetime(2020, 1, 31)
df = yf.download('AAPL', start=start_date, end=end_date)

# using the mplfinance library to make a candle chart out of the data    
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize  = (20, 10))
mpf.plot(df, ax = ax, type='candle', style = 'charles')

# plotting months as major ticks
months = mdates.MonthLocator()
months_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%b')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(months)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(months_fmt)

# plotting days as minor ticks
days = mdates.DayLocator(interval=1)
days_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%d')
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(days)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(days_fmt)
plt.tick_params(pad=10)

# create a second x-axis beneath the first x-axis to show the year in YYYY format
years = mdates.YearLocator()
years_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y')

sec_xaxis = ax.secondary_xaxis(-0.08)
sec_xaxis.xaxis.set_major_locator(years)
sec_xaxis.xaxis.set_major_formatter(years_fmt)

# Hide the second x-axis spines and ticks
sec_xaxis.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
sec_xaxis.tick_params(length=0, pad=10, labelsize=15)
```

Comment: it's most likely that `mpf` plots against range index (0..n) and just label the ticks by the date strings.

Comment: I believe pandas still registers their own converter with its own Formatters, and their converter is not compatible with Matplotlib's Formatters.  To use Matplotlib's converters you need to deregister the pandas ones:    `pd.plotting.deregister_matplotlib_converters()`. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.plotting.deregister_matplotlib_converters.html#pandas.plotting.deregister_matplotlib_converters

Comment: This issue for mplfinance plots is that the xticks are 0 indexed, as commented by @QuangHoang, which you can see by doing `ax.get_xticks()` after `mpf.plot`, this is not a datetime axis. As such, DateFormatter does not work. All of the cited links are irrelevant to mplfinance xtick questions.

Comment: This is the case because non-trading days are skipped. In order to implement that feature, the xticks are not formatted as datetimes. If you want your code to work as expected, and to have a datetime xtick format, then add `mpf.plot(..., show_nontrading=True)`

Comment: Specifically, you get 1970 because the xtick location 0, corresponds to 1970. See your [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fyfdj.png) with adding `show_nontrading=True`.